# HttpClient does not create new connections in netstat

Tags: asp.net-core, httpclient, netstat

I'm trying to recreate common scenario when creating new instances of httpClient will create leave TIME_WAIT connections.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestOne()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                using(var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"This is response - successfull");
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            var proxyHost = "ttrproxy.someproxy.net";
            var proxyPort = "8080";

            var proxy = new WebProxy
            {
                Address = new Uri($"http://{proxyHost}:{proxyPort}"),
                BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            };

            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = proxy,
                UseDefaultCredentials=true
            };


            httpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
            httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);

            return client;
        }
```

Without proxy all is the same (when instead of GetHttpClient I use just new HttpClient()).
After all I type

> netstat -abn

but I cannot see any new opened connections...

Comment: It is always recommended to use IHttpClient factory. You can check this for an example of the real life case that I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821886/ihttpclientfactory-with-autofac-in-net-4-8

Comment: " I cannot see any new opened connections..." When do you cannot see any new  opened connections? If you use [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) local without the api code , can you  see any new opened connections ? Besides, what's the system do you use ? You can check it with administrator rights. Is it affected by firewalls, etc?

Comment: What runtime are you running on?

Comment: 1. I know that it's better to use factory, I just want to check this netstats, in all courses related to that topic that netstat is showed as reference.

2. I cannot see it when I run the program and then check connections..
3. @StephenCleary I check it on windows10 and windows11 on .NET7

Comment: @ruddnisrus: I believe net7 will use the new sockets http handler which reuses connections.